# How can I prevent listview.bulder from resize itself when new data come from server

Tags: flutter, dart

I have `ListView.builder` that display data from server in stream from older to latest date dates. That means the new data always comes to the top of the `ListView.builder` and while `ListView.builder` receiving new item it resize itself so the scroll move go up step by step. how to prevent that? I have an image here:

[image]

I need number 5 to happen.

Of course I can make the property `reverse` to true. OK, this will solve one side only and the same Scenario will happen from down the page.

```
ListView.builder(
itemBuilder: myList.length,
  itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
    return myList['item']
  },
),
```

Answer (score 1):

First of all, some background on why the behavior you want to avoid happens: 
Flutter does not remember to which item the user has scrolled. Instead, it stores how far the user already scrolled, thus when rebuilding, the old scroll offset will correspond to a different item as some items have been inserted in the list prior to the one visible at a specific scroll offset. 
Here's a possible fix:
 You can give the `ListView.builder` a `ScrollController`. Using the `ScrollController` you can increase the current scroll offset by the amount of space, the new, at the top of the list inserted items occupy, like so: 
`controller.jumpTo(controller.offset + tileHeight*(newLength - _lastLength));`
Here is a small code example in which I implemented it:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(const MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  // This widget is the root of your application.
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Test',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: const MyHomePage(),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyHomePage({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<MyHomePage> createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  ScrollController controller = ScrollController();
  final tileHeight = 50.0;
  int _lastLength = -1;
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: StreamBuilder<List<String>>(
        stream: getData(),
        builder: (context, snapshot) {
          if (snapshot.hasData) {
            final newLength = snapshot.data!.length;
            if(newLength > _lastLength && _lastLength > 0){
              controller.jumpTo(controller.offset + tileHeight*(newLength - _lastLength));
            }
            _lastLength = newLength;
            return ListView.builder(
              itemCount: snapshot.data!.length,
              itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                return SizedBox(
                  height: tileHeight,
                  child: ListTile(
                    title: Text(
                      snapshot.data![index],
                    ),
                  ),
                );
              },
              controller: controller,
            );
          }
          return const CircularProgressIndicator();
        },
      ),
    );
  }

  Stream<List<String>> getData() async* {
    yield List.generate(20, (index) => index.toString());
    await Future.delayed(const Duration(seconds: 5));
    yield ["-1"] + List.generate(20, (index) => index.toString());
  }
}
```

Comment: that's would be great solution if you don't use fixed tileHeight , since the tileHeigh it's self depends on users input that would Couse  overflowed

Comment: since the tile height is dynamic what if you record the tileHeight and rescroll. So before populating the data from the server, take note of scroll, then after adding, subtract and scroll back by this height. Its just hypothesis, it might work.